# Como hago para hablilitar solo las fechas que tengo en una array (bootstrap-datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datepicker

tengo el siguiente problema.

tengo un array de fechas, y quiero que solo estas fechas se habiliten en el bootstrap-datapicker, estuve leyendo la documentación pero no encontré lo que queria!

```
fechas = ['2018-08-21', '2018-08-22', '2018-08-25', '2018-08-29'];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146382/bootstrap-datepicker-restrict-available-dates-to-be-selected

Comment: Gracias @alanfcm

Answer (score 0):

Para solo habilitar creo que no hay, pero puedes hacer lo contrario que es deshabilitar fechas, lo unico que debes hacer es hacer otro array con las fechas que se van a deshabilitar y las pasas en el parametro disableDates.

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates